# Why was sass-rails gem added to my Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubymine, sass-rails

```
Rails 5.2.2
Rubymine for the Mac 2018.3.5
```

I generated a new application, and in my Gemfile, I see:

```
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
```

I was under the impression that there's no need to include this Gem, because the Rails 5 default behavior, is to use SASS. Am I mistaken, and this is still needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gem is needed. Basically don't worry about versions of gems, this is expected. It's normal to have >100 gems soon in your app. And versions are not strict to Rails version.